# How to change searchbar padding in swift

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, padding, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I want to change my search bar padding with the text inside it. Is there any way to make it and could you give me a reference ? I want to make my text not too close with top and bottom search bar frame. I think i should say it a padding. Any reference will be helpful. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Theres an `UITextField` in your search bar and can be accessed by:

```
// Assuming your searchBar is called "searchBar"
searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as! UITextField
```

I'm not very sure what you mean in your question, but you can just play with the `UITextField` to get what you want.

Comment: What i mean is i want to make more padding space for the text inside search field, so it has more space with the search top and bottom border